# Showing this year and last year's data in one row in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a table of sales grouped by week. I want to write a query that creates a new table giving the sales of the week in question AND the sales of that item from this time last year, but my attempts either give blank cells for the this-time-last-year (TTLY) values or duplicates.

I've tried writing a subquery that takes the date, subtracts 52 weeks, and shows the value for that week, then joining that subquery to my main query.

However, that subquery isn't working: the query shows the date of a year ago correctly, but doesn't then pull the SALES for that TTLY week, only the current week.

```
with ttyl as 
(select
    date::date as date,
    (sales.date - interval '52 weeks') as date_ttly,
    ID,
    value
    from sales
    where country = 'uk' and date > '2019-08-01' and ID = '12345678')
```

In this example the subquery generates the previous year's date in the date_ttly column but pulls 2019 data in the value column.

All the WHERE conditions are just temporary so as to make building the query easier.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected result?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my phone, but the single table has columns ID, sales, date. I want a table with ID, sales, date, the date last year, and sales last year.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sales are grouped by `date` **and** by `country` only, a join on the same table should work:

```
SELECT sales1.id,
    sales1.date,
    sales1.value,
    sales2.date,
    sales2.value
FROM sales AS sales1
JOIN sales AS sales2 ON sales1.date - interval '52 weeks' = sales2.date
                    AND sales1.country = sales2.country
```

However, this also assumes that your `date` is always the same day of the week, e.g. Monday.

Comment: It is always the same day of the week (Saturday). Sales are grouped by ID, date, and country?

Comment: It worked!! I also had to group by ID :) Thank you!